LookupRows() matching blank/empty values to retrieve a row
I'm trying to get rows from a DE using the LookupRows() function. I'm checking a field for a value, but that value can be empty/blank/null. But it doesn't seem to be working.
LookupRows("DE_name","MODEL",MODEL)
In the example above I'm checking if the MODEL value in the send list/DE is equal to the MODEL value in the lookup DE. But I want to match them, even if both fields are blank/empty. This doesn't seem to work.
In general this works with AMPscript, but in the Lookup() context it doesn't seem to find a row when both values are empty.

LookupRows function does work when you put an empty string as the filter value. Try to check if it retrieves any rows by the RowCount function

Thanks. I was afraid that was the case.
